# Autowiring fails in Junit testing and spring @configuration

Tags: java, spring, junit, autowired

I have two `@Configuration` classes. I need a bean from one configuration class to another. I have autowired the configuration 1 into 2. All works fine. When executing the unit testing, am getting the below exception.

```
setUpContext(com.trafigura.titan.framework.services.messaging.loader.SpringLoadTest)
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.xxx.MessagingServicesConfig': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.xxx.EMSJMSConfig com.xxx.MessagingServicesConfig.emsJmsConfig; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type[com.xxx.EMSJMSConfig] found for dependency: 
expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

Is there anything I need to do additionally to make this working?

Below is the setup for testing.

```
@Configuration
@Import({MessagingServicesConfig.class,...,EMSJMSConfig.class
})
public class MessagingConfig {}

@Profile("EMS-MESSAGING")
@Configuration
public class EMSJMSConfig {
    @Bean
    public javax.jms.ConnectionFactory jmsSubscriberConnectionFactory() throws JMSException {
        SingleConnectionFactory singleConnectionFactory = new SingleConnectionFactory(tibjmsConnectionFactory());
        return singleConnectionFactory;
    }
}

@Configuration
public class MessagingServicesConfig {
    @Autowired
    private EMSJMSConfig emsJmsConfig;
    @Bean(destroyMethod = "shutdown")
    public MessagingService messagingService() throws JMSException {
        ...
        ConnectionFactory cf=emsJmsConfig.jmsSubscriberConnectionFactory(); // Getting NPE at this line.
    }
}
```

and finally the test class,

```
public class MessagingServicesConfigTest {
    private MessagingServicesConfig config;
    private EMSJMSConfig emsJmsConfig;
    @BeforeMethod
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        config = new MessagingServicesConfig();
        ... //what needs to be done here to have the EMSJMSConfig
    }
    @Test
    public void testBuildsCorrectService() throws JMSException {
        MessagingService service = config.messagingService();   
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: That won't help and isn't loading the configuration either. Use the proper `@ContextConfiguration` annotation to specify what to load.

Comment: Then kindly let me know how to load it?

Comment: Without seeing what you are doing now it is hard to tell. But you should be using the `SpringRunner` to run your tests and use `@ContextConfiguration` to specify which classes to load.

Answer (score 1):

By calling `new` you're creating object yourself, Spring doesn't know anything about it.

Moreover, you should have a test configuration which will be aware of your beans.

Use an appropriate `Runner` to load `SpringContext`.

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = TestConfig.class)
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
class Tests {

    @Autowired // if needed
    private MessagingServicesConfig config;
}
```

While in `TestConfig` you can create `beans` or import configuration from the Application:

```
@Configuration
@Import({MessagingServicesConfig.class})
public class TestConfig {}

@Configuration
@Import({EMSJMSConfig.class})
public class MessagingServicesConfig {}
```

Or you can refer to your config classes directly:

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {MessagingServicesConfig.class, EMSJMSConfig.class})
```

Comment: Without an `@ContextConfiguration` that won't do much (give a warning and error I suspect).

Comment: @M. Deinum, My bad, posted incomplete.